# Access attributes of class attached to GameObject

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I have a prefab with a c# script attached (ScriptA), then I instantiate a number of GameObjects of this prefab from another script (ScriptB).

```
public class ScriptA : MonoBehaviour {
    public int pos;
```

...

```
public class ScriptB : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject prefab;   
    GameObject [] all;
```

... And then at some point objects are created:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
       Vector3 v = new Vector3(i, 0, 0);
       v = v * 3;
       GameObject newObject;
       newObject = GameObject.Instantiate(prefab, v , Quaternion.identity);
       all[i] = newObject;
    }
```

So my question:

Are instances of ScriptA created with each prefab Object?
And if so, how do I access them and their attributes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `ScriptA` is attached to the instantiated prefab, you can get a reference from it using [GameObject.GetComponent](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponent.html) method, for example:

```
ScriptA  aInstance = newObject.GetComponent<ScriptA >();
int p = aInstnace.pos;
```

the you can call access the desired properties or methods on `ScriptA` instance (`aInstance`).

Comment: It was so simple I feel dumb. I just started learning Unity.
So thanks a lot! :)